# Tool Command Languare Byte String loop

Tags: foreach, tcl

I am using tcl and my data looks like this `b'{{"George" "F" "Smith" "Nevada" "UCLA"} {"Mike" "Z" "Jones" "California" "NU"}}'`

I am removing `b'` and the ending `'`.

```
set testData "b'{ {\"George\" \"F\" \"Smith\" \"Nevada\" \"UCLA\"} {\"Mike\" \"Z\" \"Jones\" \"California\" \"NU\"} }'"
set testData [string range $testData 2 end-1]
```

leaving `{"George" "F" "Smith" "Nevada" "UCLA"} {"Mike" "Z" "Jones" "California" "NU"}`
How do I turn this into a list so I can loop over the data. What i have tried does not work.

```
set list2 [list $testData] (does not work)
foreach item $list2 {
    puts "[lindex $item 0 ] [lindex $item 1 ]" 
}
```

Comment: The "make this be a real canonical list for me" call would be `[lrange $testData 0 end]` but you probably don't need it; it's not a common operation given how Tcl thinks about types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember in tcl, everything's a string, but if it looks like a list/number/etc., it can be used as a list/number/etc.

After stripping the leading `b'` and trailing `'`, you're left with a string that looks like a single-element list - where that single element itself is a list. So you can do something like:

```
foreach item [lindex $testData 0] {
    puts "[lindex $item 0] [lindex $item 1]" 
}
```

to iterate over its elements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shawn's advice, the [`lassign`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm) command is handy:

```
lassign [lindex $testData 0] george mike

puts [join $george :]   ;# George:F:Smith:Nevada:UCLA
puts [join $mike :]     ;# Mike:Z:Jones:California:NU
```

Comment: It's more common to use `lassign` to either split a record into fields or to slice an element or two off the front of a list.